# Click next button of Bing Image search

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, bing

I use chrome to inspect the element of the next button of Bing image search, the step are

1. Search smoke by Bing image search
2. Move mouse to the "next image result" button and inspect the element by chrome

following are the results inspect by chrome

[image]

I give following javascript a try but none of them work

```
//error message : document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function
document.getElementsByClassName("iv_button").click()
//error message : Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
document.getElementsByClassName("iv_button")[0].click()
//error message : Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
document.getElementsByClassName("iv_button")[1].click()
//error message : Cannot read property 'click' of null
document.getElementById("iol_navr").click()
```

How could I go to the next page(except of using Bing api)?

Edit : As omegastripes mentioned,document.getElementById("iol_navr").click() work. It do not work on my case because the html contents of my page did not update.

Comment: I tried `document.getElementById("iol_navr").click()` in Chrome console, and it works just fine, as well as `iol_navr.click()`.

Comment: It's not quite clear what do mean saying "html contents of my page did not update", and what is the actual issue is. Could you show the entire code you are using, and clarify what steps should be done to reproduce such behavior.

Comment: @omegastripes Thanks, Codes are written by QWebEnginePage of Qt5, it is more like a Qt5 webengine problem rather than javascript problem, I think open another question is a better choice